# I'm applying for UK Visit visa. Should I be worried about my bank statement that has a big deposit if its from myself?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for a UK Visit Visa. I've been reading online here and have read a lot about fund parking.
When I looked at my 6 months bank statement, I realized that I have a big deposit that's around more than 3x my monthly income. But, that deposit came from my other bank account.
Would they still suspect it to be fund parking if I can show the bank statement from my 2 accounts to demonstrate that the big deposit was just from me transferring a big chunk of money from one account to another?

Would it be better to delay my application till the big deposit doesn't reflect in the 6 months statement?

Thanks

Comment: They'll want to know how you came by the big chunk of money in your other account. Can you show it was legitimate? If not, waiting would be a lot safge.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Its just accumulated savings from my payroll after expenses. Do you think showing my payslips would suffice? Thanks

Comment: Can you go 6 months farther back before the big withdrawal from the other account, and present a legal and consistent history for that other account as well? And they'll want to know why you have two accounts. While one can present explanations and provide documents, the more you have to explain and present documents, the more they'll see your application as unusual and you'll increasingly risk denial.

Comment: Thanks so much! Will give more bank statements then!

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Is it really that odd to have two accounts in the UK? In the US, I think most people have "checking" and "savings", and usually move money between them fairly regularly.

Comment: Not so much "savings" any more (banks' and building societies' rates of return are low), but other "investment" accounts instead. The issue, as I see it, is that the more the application diverges from UKVI's Platonic ideal of one account, the more likely the examination will be more rigorous, and the more likely to generate a refusal if, in their view, the applicant's finances are unusual.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: What is your belief that UKVI’s “platonic ideal” is a single account based on?  I take your point that anything *unusual* or *complex* may attract scrutiny and raise the chance of difficulties.  But everywhere I’ve lived (the UK, US, and mainland Europe), it was *completely* standard to have at least two accounts (one for everyday purposes, one for long-term savings/investment) — I see no reason to think UKVI would find such an arrangement concerning.

Comment: @PLL I think you're likely correct that having two accounts should by itself raise few eyebrows.  However, anything more complicated or unusual than the norm, or circumstances requiring extensive explanation, will risk greater scrutiny and negative judgment.

Comment: I have four bank accounts, and my finances aren't in any way unusual. That's not counting investment accounts with financial institutions other than banks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be a problem, but the solution is simple. You should include the statements from the accounts you transferred the money from. This will give a better picture of your finances and clear up any problem with where the money came from.

There is no need to delay the application.